# Options Missing in the View Layer Properties Panel

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, properties

I am pretty new to Blender, although I could not find a similar enough question for the problem I am experiencing. When I select an object in my scene, the materials section on the properties panel is completely blank, and likewise if I add a new object. In addition, I am noticing that some of the other properties are missing options as well.

Using Blender 2.83.50

See screenshots:

1. Object with Material already assigned
   [image]
2. New Cube I just added
   [image: New Cube without materials assigned yet]

I am using cycles for the render engine, and the options do display when I move to the shading panel (for the material properties). This last picture is the Layers tab, which also looks empty:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Cycles is enabled in the user preferences.

Edit > Preferences > Add-ons

[image]

Also, make sure this is unchecked in your current workspace :

[image]

If you have to have it checked, make sure the cycles add-on is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You have to change Render Engine from Workbench to something else

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the new Blender version, Blender 2.9. It just came out recently. And if that's a bug, it will probably be fixed in the new version. You could also just try scrolling up on the panel and see if Blender on default made the panel scrolled way down, so it looks like nothing is there.
Hope this helps.